# how to handle CriteriaBuilder and predicates in junit mockito testcase

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, jpa, junit, mockito

```
        Impl.java
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
         public List<SearchDTO> findByCriteria(SearchCriteriaDTO SearchCriteriaDTO) {
                CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Search> query = builder.createQuery(Search.class);
                Root<Search> repls = query.from(Search.class);
```

final int QUERY_LIMIT = Integer.parseInt(queryLimit);

```
    List<UUID> statusIds = SearchCriteriaDTO.getStatusIds();
    if (statusIds != null && !statusIds.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(builder.and(repl.get("statusId").in(statusIds)));
    }
        -----------------------------
```

below is the test class for impl class.

```
        impltest.java
        ---------------------------
//mocking the services.
     @Mock
        private SearchMapper SearchMapper;
        @Mock
        private SearchRepository SearchRepository;

        @Mock
        private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

        @Mock
        private Root root;

        @Mock
        private EntityManager entityManager;
        @Rule
        public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

        @Mock
        CriteriaQuery<Search>  criteriaQuery;

        @Mock
        Root<UUID> statusId;

        @Mock
        Path<String> path;

        @Mock
        Expression expr;

        @Mock
        Predicate predicate;

        @Mock
        TypedQuery<Member> querymem;

        @Mock
        Root<Search> rSearchRootMock;

        @InjectMocks

        private SearchServiceImpl SearchService;

      @Value("${query.limit}")

        String queryLimit;

        @Before
        public void init() {

            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(SearchService);
            SearchRootMock = mock(Root.class);
        }
          @Test
            public void test_findby_criteria() {
        hen(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder); when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Search.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
                when(criteriaQuery.from(Search.class)).thenReturn(SearchRootMock);
                Path statusIdMock = mock(Path.class);

                //when(Integer.parseInt(queryLimit)).thenReturn(1);
                String status = "statusId";

                Expression<String> doublePath = root.get(status);
                when(root.get((status))).thenReturn((Path) doublePath);
                when(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String>get(status))).thenReturn(expr);
                when(criteriaBuilder.equal(expr,status.toUpperCase())).thenReturn(predicate);

                when(root.get("statusId")).thenReturn(path);
                when(this.SearchService.findByCriteria(SearchCriteriaDTO)).thenReturn(Searches);

        here i am trying to mock the predicate but getting null point exception due to root.get("statusId").
        please let me know how to mock it.
```

here are the issues

how to handle and mock the  @Value("${query.limit}") where i am reading limit from application properties file.
getting null point exception in predicate line.
 predicates.add(builder.and(repl.get("statusId").in(statusIds)));

```
     not able to map the column name here for repl.get("statusId") where getting null.
```

please help me to solve this problem.Thanks

below is the error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${query.limit}"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.capturerx.cumulus4.replenishment.impl.ReplenishmentSearchServiceImplTest.test_findby_criteria_for_success(ReplenishmentSearchServiceImplTest.java:118)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

---

getting java.lang.NullPointerException at line
query.select(replenishments).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

Comment: Please try to find solution for the above issue.